# Laravel how to get auth user details in apiResources controller

Tags: laravel-5

How can I get auth user details in api controller in laravel
I am using laravel version 5.8

This is my apiResources route

```
Route::apiResources([
'employeeapi' => 'API\EmployeeController',
]);
```

and my controller is

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller {
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I access `Auth::user()` inside the `store` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following middleware on your **api** routes to use laravel sessions if the user was logged in to a session in one of your **web** routes.

```php
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
```

> However you probably want your **api** to use some kind of token based authentication. [laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) has great tools for that. Because using sessions in an api might become messy.